# How to refactor my code to fix es-linting warning when calling a React hook inside of a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

So I have two custom hooks right now. One that returns an array of team IDs and another that accepts one team ID as the argument and returns all the data for the team.

I want to loop through the array of team IDs and pass each id into the hook that fetches the data. But I am getting an eslint error **"React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render."**. Does anyone know how to refactor my code so I can avoid this warning? I know you aren't supposed to call React hooks inside of loops but not sure how else to accomplish what I need.

I have also tried combining both hooks into one hook but that gave me the same error because inside of useGetTeamData, I need to utilize the UseQuery hook from the apollo framework so I would again be calling a hook inside of a loop.

This is my parent component that calls both of these hooks

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useGetTeamIds, useGetTeamData } from "../../hooks";

const teamIds = useGetTeamIds(); // ex: ["21", "25", "55", "63"];
const collection_of_teamData = [];
for (const id of teamIds) {
    collection_of_teamData.push(useGetTeamData(id));
}

// Do something with collection of team data here
```

Comment: You can't call the hook in the loop. Either refactor `useGetTeamData` to accept multiple ids or pass each id to a Component that calls `useGetTeamData` at the top level

Comment: Yes Dave, fixed that typo. And @pilchard how useGetTeamData is implemented, it can only accept 1 ID at a time. And the number of team IDs will be different for each user.

Comment: Then you'll need to split it out to its own component

Answer (score 0):

Since you've indicated that you are not able to refactor `useGetTeamData()` to accept multiple `id`s one option is to declare a child Component which accepts an `id` as a prop and then calls `useGetTeamData()` at the top level as required. This still keeps control of the collection in the parent, but delegates individual element control to the child.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useGetTeamIds, useGetTeamData } from '../../hooks';

function Teams() {
  const teamIds = useGetTeamIds(); // ex: ["21", "25", "55", "63"];

  return (
    <div>
      {teamIds.map((id) => (
        <Team key={id} id={id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Team({ id }) {
  const teamData = useGetTeamData(id);

  return (
    <div>
      <H1>{teamData.name}</H1>
    </div>
  );
}
```